# Django return csv file to user in File Field

Tags: python, django, csv

I have function returns `csv` file and want to add it to File Field in Django model

I tried to convert it to pandas data frame then to str by using `to_csv` method

```
label_name = 'labeled' + data.name
labeled_data = np.concatenate([data, model.labels_.reshape(-1, 1)], 
axis=1)
columns = [x for x in range(labeled_data.shape[1])]
labeled_data_file = pd.DataFrame(data=labeled_data, columns=columns)
labeled_data_file = labeled_data_file.to_csv(index=False, header=True)
instance.labeled_data.save(label_name, labeled_data_file, save=False)
```

however, it returns 
error:

> read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used `ContentFile` class and it worked

```
labeled_data_file = pd.DataFrame(data=labeled_data, columns=columns)
temp_file = ContentFile(labeled_data_file.to_csv(index=False, header=True))
instance.labeled_data.save(name=label_name, content=temp_file, save=False)
```